# specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application. JAVA

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I'm trying to connect to a database made by MS Access using Java, but I cannot seem to manage. I am using JDBC ODBC bridge and I'm getting this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

Answer (score 1):

64-bit vs 32-bit... you must match your version of Access.

Comment: thanks elliott.....im using 64 bit java and 32 bit office.....how to correct it

Comment: Upgrade to 64 bit office, or downgrade to 32 bit java.

Comment: no other go...??...thanks any way...

Comment: @Pradeep From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2810790/2970947), Use [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en).

Comment: Try to answer some questions. Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).